# Does the direction of angular momentum of a table fan different for two people standing behind the fan and in front of the fan?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum

Does angular momentum of a table fan depend on place of observation?

What is its direction of angular momentum of a fan when I stand behind a table fan? In front of a table fan? And along the same plane as that table fan?

Answer (score 0):

Angular momentum always depends on the chosen origin point. Angular momentum for any infinitesimal mass is $\vec r\times m\vec v$ , where $\vec r$ is the vector from a chosen origin point to the position of the infinitesimal mass. Choose a different origin, get a different answer.

But, if net Linear Momentum is zero, that is a special case, and angular momentum is the same from any chosen origin point. Changes in the angular momentum of one infinitesimal is balanced by opposing changes to other infinitesimals.

So, if the overall linear momentum of the fan is zero, then No, no difference.

A.M. around Origin  :  $\vec L(O) = \sum \vec r_i\times m_i\vec v_i$

A.M around alternate : $\vec L(O + \vec R) = \sum (\vec r_i-\vec R)\times m_i\vec v_i$

distribute : $\vec L(O + \vec R) = \sum \vec r_i\times m_i\vec v_i -\vec R\times \sum m_i\vec v_i$

if linear momentum $=0=\sum m_i\vec v_i$

then : $\vec L(O + \vec R) = \sum \vec r_i\times m_i\vec v_i=\vec L(O)$

Comment: The angular momentum is a vector at right angles to the disk of rotation. When you look in the direction of the vector, the rotation is clockwise. When you look in the opposite direction, the rotation is counter-clockwise.

Comment: In the textbook "Classical Mechanics" by Herbert Goldstein, this is expressed as "The total angular momentum is equal to the the angular momentum around the center of mass plus the angular momentum of the center of mass".